# Unable to use an acronym for a routing namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to use a namespace that is acronym (all caps), but can't seem to figure it out. I always get an "unable to autoload" error message.

Here is an example:

routes.rb:

```
  namespace 'ASAP' do
    resources :foos
  end
```

asap/foos_controller.rb:

```
class ASAP::FoosController < ApplicationController
  def index
    head :ok
  end
end
```

config/inflections.rb:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym 'ASAP'
end
```

Error message:

```
Unable to autoload constant Asap::FoosController, expected app/controllers/asap/foos_controller.rb to define it
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'd bet that your inflections file isn't getting loaded. Try putting the `inflections.rb` file in `config/initializers`.

Comment: Doh! I had it in the wrong folder! Post your answer and I can accept!

Comment: Cheers, Tom! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything in your code looks good, it's just that the `inflections.rb` file needs to get loaded by being put in `config/initializers` instead of the `/config` path.

From Rails:

> ```
> # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
> # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.
> ```

Instead of here:

```
config
└── inflections.rb
```

Here:

```
config
└── initializers
    └── inflections.rb
```

Comment: Oops! Thanks for the catch!